# MMScrollPresenter for more images?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiscrollview

I used MMScrollPresenter for 4 images. It is perfectly done. But now i want to used this for dynamic, how can i done. I know this can be done using for loop.

```
NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"mountains.jpg",@"forest.jpg", nil];
for(int i=0;i<array.count;i++)
{
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",array[i]]]];
    [imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, scrollImg.frame.size.width, scrollImg.frame.size.height)];
    Page = [[MMScrollPage alloc] init];
    [Page.backgroundView addSubview:imageView];
}
[scrollImg addMMScrollPageArray:@[Page]];
```

After using this code, scroll view not working. Anybody can help me.